# .htaccess redirect php query

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

i'm trying to redirect vendor.php?id=8 to a cleaner path
i'm using this :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^vendor\.php$ /new-location/%1/? [L,R=301]
```

it seems to redirect to the right path but i'm not getting the page content:

"Object not found! error 404"

1. vendor.php placed in root
2. id number = id from mysql table

Comment: Looks like you need URL rewriting and not a redirection. The `R=301` flag means that every call to `vendor.php?id=8` will redirect to `/new-location/8/` which is obviously not a real page.

Comment: try this one `RewriteRule ^vendor\.php$ /new-location/%1/? [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a local (internal) redirect, which reaches the PHP script where your logic resides (currently, it is `vendor.php`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /vendor\.php\?id=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^vendor\.php$ /new-location/%1/? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^new-location/(\d+)/?$ /vendor.php?id=$1 [L]
```